# Symfony asset image not found

Tags: php, symfony, assets, symfony5

I would like to display an image on my page, like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('image.png') }}"/>
```

The image is located in `assets/image.png`

If I open the page, the result is this:

```
<img src="/image.png"/>
```

But the image can not be found on that url.
I suspect, that the `image.png` has to be copied somehow to the `/public directory`, but Symfony did not copy it there, and I have no idea which command to run, to automatically copy the required assets like that.

Comment: Could you please include the Symfony version details in the question?

Comment: @plbit I use Symfony 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you do a special treatment on the image, you don't really need to put it in the assets folder. You can just put it in the public folder, in a subfolder ideally.

Or you can keep it in the assets folder, and use this : https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/copy-files.html

To copy it with webpack on build time.

Answer (score 2):

Create folder in `public`, for example `images`, and put your image to this folder. Then in template you should use your image as follow

```html
<img src="{{ asset('images/<YOUR_IMAGE>') }}" />
```